# Optimize testing all combinations of rows from multiple NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, optimization

I have three **NumPy arrays** of ints, same number of columns, arbitrary number of rows each. I am interested in all instances where a row of the first one plus a row of the second one gives a row of the third one ([3, 1, 4] + [1, 5, 9] = [4, 6, 13]).

Here is a pseudo-code:

```
for i, j in rows(array1), rows(array2):
    if i + j is in rows(array3):
        somehow store the rows this occured at (eg. (1,2,5) if 1st row of 
        array1 + 2nd row of array2 give 5th row of array3)
```

I will need to run this for very big matrices so I have two questions:

(1) I can write the above using nested loops but is there a quicker way, perhaps **list comprehensions** or **itertools**?

(2) What is the fastest/most memory-efficient **way to store** the triples? Later I will need to create a heatmap using two as coordinates and the first one as the corresponding value eg. point (2,5) has value 1 in the pseudo-code example.

Would be very grateful for any tips - I know this sounds quite simple but it needs to run fast and I have very little experience with optimization.

**edit:** My ugly code was requested in comments

```
import numpy as np

#random arrays
A = np.array([[-1,0],[0,-1],[4,1], [-1,2]])
B = np.array([[1,2],[0,3],[3,1]])
C = np.array([[0,2],[2,3]])

#triples stored as numbers with 2 coordinates in a otherwise-zero matrix
output_matrix = np.zeros((B.shape[0], C.shape[0]), dtype = int)
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[0]):
        for k in range(C.shape[0]):
            if np.array_equal((A[i,] + B[j,]), C[k,]):
                output_matrix[j, k] = i+1

print(output_matrix)
```

Comment: Share your nested loops based working solution alongwith a minimal sample?

Comment: Is the number of columns always small? And are the ints themselves small? Do you have an indication for the typical or worst case number of rows?

Comment: @Divakar code added.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn the numbers will be mostly very small: -10 < n < 10, however, the number of rows can be quite overwhelming. Typically, about 10 columns, thousands of rows. To be more specific, my nested-loops-based MATLAB code for this can do it for 14 columns and 140, 500, 3600 rows in about 3 minutes. Anything better than that would be amazing!

Comment: Are you sure about that output? Shouldn't that be `N x 3` array? Also, I am not convinced if storing `i+1` is the desired one.

Comment: Yes, quite sure - number 4 in position (row 3, column 2) means that 4th row of A plus 3rd row of B gives 2nd row of C. (human-counting)

Comment: `A` has four rows ( 0 to 3). It doesn't have `4` as row index. But, you have `4` in `output_matrix`.

Comment: That's why I said 'human-counting' - rows are 1,2,3,4. If that irritates you feel free to erase +1 in the last line of the loop, but then you don't know if 0 in output_matrix represents the first row of A or nothing at all... But as I said, part of the question is how to store these for later heat-mapping so if have any tips, they will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### (1) Improvements

You can use sets for the final result in the third matrix, as `a + b = c` must hold identically. This already replaces one nested loop with a constant-time lookup. I will show you an example of how to do this below, but we first ought to introduce some notation.

For a set-based approach to work, we need a hashable type. Lists will thus not work, but a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) will: it is an ordered, immutable structure. There is, however, a problem: tuple addition is defined as appending, that is,

`(0, 1) + (1, 0) = (0, 1, 1, 0).`

This will not do for our use-case: we need element-wise addition. As such, we subclass the built-in tuple as follows,

```
class AdditionTuple(tuple):

    def __add__(self, other):
        """
        Element-wise addition.
        """
        if len(self) != len(other):
            raise ValueError("Undefined behaviour!")

        return AdditionTuple(self[idx] + other[idx]
                             for idx in range(len(self)))
```

Where we override the default behaviour of `__add__`. Now that we have a data-type amenable to our problem, let's prepare the data.

You give us,

```
A = [[-1, 0], [0, -1], [4, 1], [-1, 2]]
B = [[1, 2], [0, 3], [3, 1]]
C = [[0, 2], [2, 3]]
```

To work with. I say,

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

A = [AdditionTuple(item) for item in A]
B = [AdditionTuple(item) for item in B]
C = {tuple(item): SimpleNamespace(idx=idx, values=[])
     for idx, item in enumerate(C)}
```

That is, we modify `A` and `B` to use our new data-type, and turn `C` into a dictionary which supports (amortised) `O(1)` look-up times.

We can now do the following, eliminating one loop altogether,

```
from itertools import product

for a, b in product(enumerate(A), enumerate(B)):
    idx_a, a_i = a
    idx_b, b_j = b

    if a_i + b_j in C:  # a_i + b_j == c_k, identically
        C[a_i + b_j].values.append((idx_a, idx_b))
```

Then,

```
>>>print(C)
{(2, 3): namespace(idx=1, values=[(3, 2)]), (0, 2): namespace(idx=0, values=[(0, 0), (1, 1)])}
```

Where for each value in `C`, you get the index of that value (as `idx`), and a list of tuples of `(idx_a, idx_b)` whose elements of `A` and `B` together sum to the value at `idx` in `C`.

Let us briefly analyse the complexity of this algorithm. Redefining the lists `A`, `B`, and `C` as above is linear in the length of the lists. Iterating over `A` and `B` is of course in `O(|A| * |B|)`, and the nested condition computes the element-wise addition of the tuples: this is linear in the length of the tuples themselves, which we shall denote `k`. The whole algorithm then runs in `O(k * |A| * |B|)`.

This is a substantial improvement over your current `O(k * |A| * |B| * |C|)` algorithm.

### (2) Matrix plotting

Use a [`dok_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html), a sparse SciPy matrix representation. Then you can use any heatmap-plotting library you like on the matrix, e.g. [Seaborn's heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).

Comment: Thanks for a thorough analysis! The only issue I have with this approach is that you get the rows which added, not their indexes. Instead of (-1, 2) (3, 1) (2, 3), I need something like (3, 2 ,1) - 3rd row of A + 2nd row of B = 1st row of C...

Comment: @PetrJakubčík I think this now answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

We can leverage [`broadcasting`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) to perform all those summations and comparison in a vectorized manner and then use `np.where` on it to get the indices corresponding to the matching ones and finally index and assign -

```
output_matrix = np.zeros((B.shape[0], C.shape[0]), dtype = int)

mask = ((A[:,None,None,:] + B[None,:,None,:]) == C).all(-1)

I,J,K = np.where(mask)
output_matrix[J,K] = I+1
```